# How can I make a SVG element clickable on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, ecmascript-6

I am using React Native with Expo and I have 4 SVG elements that I need them to be clickable. This is the code for each of these:

```
  <Svg.G
    id="Passangers-Going-B"
    onPress={() => console.log(`${cardinalPoint} Avatar Was Clicked`)}
   >
...
```

With that code I am able to click on the SVG element but the weird thing is that when I try to click on another element the click is still firing the event of the last element I clicked on.

[I recorded a video with the behavior](https://monosnap.com/file/PMvw5gQzSx0YpnTSmWXjthtEKzvDOK)

So, is there a better way to do this? All I need is to click on those SVG elements in order to change to a new route.

Any ideas?

I am using SVG from expo. `import { Svg } from 'expo';` -> https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/svg/

I also created a Snack but I don't see it is working at all -> https://snack.expo.io/@maketroli/expo.svg-example?session_id=snack-session-_9YKofW2Y

What I see is that if I click on one of the elements the click gets stuck there because if I click a new element it throws the function of the last clicked element. I have to click around 3 times the new element in order to focus the click on that element.

I saw something about [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder) but I don't know this has something to do with it.

Comment: Did you try ```onClick={...}``` instead of onPress

Comment: Hi @Mulli, it is React Native. So `onPress` is the way to go.

Comment: There is no onClick event in RN..

Comment: True. Just noticed. Please look at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches I saw some simple examples there...

Comment: Expo handles WebViews, since the post has reactjs tag it was not that obvious.

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap your SVG into a Component that aims only to handle the Press event.

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(`${cardinalPoint} Avatar Was Clicked`)}>
    <Svg.G
        id="Passangers-Going-B"
    />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You will need to style it appropriatly.

Comment: If I do that, the Expo client closes and the SVG goes away.

Comment: I wrapped the component with `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and the SVG is there but it has the same behavior.

Comment: Using `TouchableOpacity`, wrap the whole block into a View.

Comment: I think it doesn't have nothing to do with what you mention. I've tried many many ways already and I can not get this to work.